# How to redirect to my client application after logging in Identity Server without registering my client application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I have my MVC client application. I load the Identity Server login page through Implicit flow. The Identity Server has a redirect uri (a registered client). When that redirect uri is loaded, after successful login, I can get the access token from it.

But, I need to get the access token by redirecting it to my (unregistered) MVC client application. I can get this done by registering my client application with the ID Server.

However, I just want to know if I could get the access token by redirecting to my (unregistered) client application. Is this possible in ASP.NET MVC? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is - **No**, this is not possible.

Your app should be registered as an Identity Server `client` so that it can be authenticated and then your user will receive the access token.

If not - the identity server will send an error (most likely `unauthorized_client`).

And think about it, the simplest explanation here - if your client is not registered (with all the properties like redirect urls, etc.), how Identity Server will know where to send the access_token?

There are other approaches, to get token, based on user credentials (resource owner password grant type), but then you don't have a client, **AND** it is sort of considered as an [anti pattern](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I get an unauthorized client error. One of my friends achieved this using WebView control in Windows application. So, I just wanted to know is that a totally different context? Impossible in Web applications? Thanks for the reply once again.

Comment: If we compare my MVC app with his WPF app, both are not registered in ID Server. But, still he's able to get the access token.

Comment: but he is not using implicit flow or any of the flows suitable for web applications

Comment: Great. Thanks. Marked as answer.